# Is it possible to have auto-run script to open up a certain file when a thumbdrive is inserted?

Tags: windows-7, usb-drive

I am trying to find a way to  make an auto-run script that when you inserted a thumbdrive into a pc it would open a certain file on the thumb? would be for windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) file in the root of the thumbdrive.